# WPF image source

Tags: .net, wpf, image

I have a wpf page defined in a runtime bound dll.
I am trying to place an image on the page from a folder in the main app.

The main as is called "Panel".
I am doing this:

```
    <Image Source="/Panel;component/Images/LRL.bmp" Height="46" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="306,90,0,0" Name="imgLRL" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127"  />
```

While the image resolves at design time, it is blank when run.  Any suggestions?

I just tried, per suggestion:

```
    <Image Height="46" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="306,90,0,0" Name="imgLRL" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127" Source="pack://application:,,,/Panel;component/Images/LRL.bmp" />
```

but same thing

Comment: Maybe you can try full URI: pack://application:,,,/RuntimeBound.dll;component/Images/LRL.bmp ?

Comment: Have you tried Snoop to ensure that the URI is set correctly?  http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/

Comment: Snoop is what helped me resolve this.  I did not know of this utility.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Snoop** helped me resolve this.  Thanks for the turn on to a new utility for me.

Answer (score 0):

When I added an images, I have a subfolder called images and I do something like this

```
<Image Source="Images/someimage.bmp" />
```

Maybe this is what you need to.

Comment: I did this as can be seen in path above